# problem installing sqlite3 using apt-get install

Tags: sqlite3

Installation hangs at 4% completion due to a prompt requesting acceptance of Oracle's license agreement. No way to respond interactively.

Comment: You are sure it is sqlite3 you are trying to install? This is a very small package, free software and will not ask a licence agreement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually on these screens you need to press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to highlight `<OK>` button.

It works that way on a few EULAs (End User License Agreements)